# brain teaser that has me totally confused

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

A man stole \$50 from a shop owner. He came back and used the same \$50 to purchase a bread that cost \$40 and received \$10 change. How much money in all did the shop owner lose?

Comment: $50? How is this a brain-teaser or even a math problem?

Comment: $\$$10 and the cost of the bread? So $\$$50?

Comment: Well, after the theft it was business as usual wasn't it? It's not like the owner would lose more money if someone *else* came and bought the exact same bread.

Comment: actually it's less than 50, assuming that the shop owner didn't buy the bread for 40 dollars himself.

Comment: Well, no. If the owner had not been stolen from, they would have still sold the bread to someone else and made money.

Comment: If the owner were to file an insurance report, they would report the loss as 50, no?

Answer (score 3):

It's $(40 + 10) = 50$. Understand it like this:

> The man stole the money and gave it back to the shop owner in order to purchase the product, so this cancels each other. But the shop owner gave him the bread which costs $\$40$ and $\$10$ change. So, this is the extra money which he loses.